# German conversation examples

Tags: phrase, learning

I am looking for practice conversations in German, things like

- A: Hi I would like to buy this fan, how much is it?
- B: It is 20 EUR, there is a used one for 10 EUR though
- C: Does the used one work properly?

Are there such things in standard exams or can I find similar conversations online?

Comment: [Lingvist](https://lingvist.io/) offers "reading lists" in several languages, for example with short articles, jokes or dialogs. I've seen the reading lists in their DE -> EN and EN -> FR sections, and they seem at least similar to what you're looking for. According to [this blog post](https://lingvist.io/blog/2016/05/04/launching-new-languages/) they're planning to launch a EN -> DE section in the fall, so I'd assume there'll be a German reading list then as well.

Answer (score 4):

YouTube is a very good source for conversational examples. A recent favourite channel for me is "Easy German" - for instance, [this video](https://youtu.be/08nQNHUyrvA) has a number of phrases that you'd commonly hear at a German supermarket. What I especially like about this series is that they have parallel subtitles (in German, and then English in a smaller font) and a lot of casual conversations.

Another option is podcasts. Radiolingua make a number of good *Coffee Break* language series, including German. I've not used the German one yet, but when I was learning French, I found that one very useful. I believe they offer transcripts of dialogues as well, but possibly only for paid members (it wasn't something that I was using at the time, since I was tending to use them while driving, so I simply subscribed with a podcast app).

A third option is a course like the "Teach Yourself", Assimil, or Pimsleur series. [This post](http://www.fluentin3months.com/best-course/) on Benny Lewis' *Fluent in Three Months* website is a good guide in choosing a course that matches your learning style and experience.

Finally, if you are looking for a bit more direct guidance, it may be worth finding a language teacher on a site like iTalki. They would then be able to take you through examples on a topic of your choosing. This can be especially useful if you are looking for a lot of feedback, if you're not sure about the material, or even if you are looking for material on a niche topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cleverbot for conversation. Not only will you be able to learn reading but having conversations in German.

I recommend reading books, which will help you a lot, even if you don't understand everything!

But here are some Links:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvfBHkPn8P4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0-zlsHwYXY

you can also download the app by BBC. In the app, you can here two people talking with each other and can read what they are saying.